# Solution To Inequality: $q>\frac{x-y}{(1+x)(2+y)}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

I am studying the following inequality:

$$q>\frac{x-y}{(1+x)(2+y)}$$

where $1>q>0$ and $x>y>1$.  Wolframalpha provides the following solutions:

1. $1>q\geq\frac{1}{3}$ with $x>y>1$.
2. $\frac{1}{3}>q>0$ with $x>\frac{1+3q}{1-3q}$ and  $y>\frac{x-2q-2qx}{1+q+qx}$.
3. $\frac{1}{3}>q>0$ with $\frac{1+3q}{1-3q}\geq x>y$.

I can show that solutions 2. and 3. are sufficient, but I am stuck at providing a proof of solution 1.  I can plot the inequality and can verify solution 1 graphically but this does not suggest a method of proof to me.

I would like a method of showing that $1>q\geq\frac{1}{3}$ constitutes a solution to this inequality when $x>y>1$.

Apologies in advance if this is obvious! Many thanks.

Comment: What do you want to solve? Please clarify the question.

Comment: @Kumar I would like a method of demonstrating that 1>q>1/3 and x>y>1 constitutes a solution to the inequality.  Apologies if this was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to investigate the case where $x>y>1$. Let $y=1+z$ and $x=1+z+r$ where $z,r>0$. We have

$$\frac{r}{(2+r+z)(3+z)}<\frac{r}{3(2+r)}=\frac{1}{3\left(1+\frac2r\right)}<\frac13$$

Does this suffice?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Many thanks.  I had previous tried setting x=y+r for some r>0 but had not thought to do something similar for y.